# Binding slider to 3D line movement action in XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have build a WPF 3D project using C# in windows 7.
I have just created 2 sliders(vertical and horizontal)and 2 3D lines (vertical and horizontal), want to bind slider to 3D line movement action, respectively.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="STIGenericReport.UserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:tool3d="clr-namespace:_3DTools;assembly=3DTools"
Height="407" Width="633" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" Focusable="False">
<Grid Name="maingrid" Background="White" Height="405" Width="616" MinWidth="500">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="619*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height ="574*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="26" MinHeight="16" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewport3D Name="mainViewport" ClipToBounds = "False"  
                IsHitTestVisible="false"
                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Margin="12,52,144,47">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <OrthographicCamera x:Name="camera" Width="2"
                FarPlaneDistance="10"
                NearPlaneDistance="1" 
                LookDirection="0,0,-1"
                UpDirection="0,1,0"
                Position="0,0,2" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport3D.Children>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light1">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="1, 1, -1" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light2">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-1, 1, -1" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Light3">
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="0,-1,-0.5" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D Points ="0,100,0,0,-100,0" Color="Black" Thickness="2"/>
            <tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D Points ="-100,0,0,100,0,0" Color="Black" Thickness="2"/>
        </Viewport3D.Children>
    </Viewport3D>

    <Canvas x:Name="canvasOn3D" Background="#00E6FFFF" 
            Margin="20,52,102,18"></Canvas>
    <Label Content="Trayinfo" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,0,0,0" Name="lblTrayinfo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,257" Name="btn9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,232" Name="btn8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,149,0,207" Name="btn7" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,182" Name="btn6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,157" Name="btn5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,132" Name="btn4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,107" Name="btn3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,82" Name="btn2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,57" Name="btn1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="499,0,0,282" Name="btn10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,57" Name="lbl1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,82" Name="lbl2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,107" Name="lbl3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,132" Name="lbl4" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,157" Name="lbl5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,182" Name="lbl6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,207" Name="lbl7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,232" Name="lbl8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,257" Name="lbl9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,282" Name="lbl10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="45" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
    <Label Content="Pacakage info" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="32" Name="lblPkgname" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="20,371,102,2" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,357,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="484"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-148,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="326">
        <Slider.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="89.89"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Slider.RenderTransform>
    </Slider>
</Grid>
```

```
  namespace _3DTools
  {
  public class ScreenSpaceLines3D : ModelVisual3D
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThicknessProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty;

    public ScreenSpaceLines3D();

    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public double Thickness { get; set; }
    public Point3DCollection Points { get; set; }

    public void MakeWireframe(Model3D model);
   }
}
```

I want to achieve this function:
when I move the horizontal slider, the vertical line move horizontally;
when I move the vertical slider, the horizontal line move vertically.

How add such kind of binding? I have tried to use normal method but failed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's going to be very difficult for people to answer your question without seeing the implementation of `tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D`.

Comment: tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D is a public  API: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1869c81b-ffc5-4ba6-8ba6-2a08fff6b076/screenspacelines3d-transform?forum=wpf, not defined by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your horizontal slider a minimum and maximum value:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="-1" Maximum="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,357,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="484" />
```

And then apply a transform offset to your horizontal line, binding OffsetY to the slider's value:

```
<tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D Points ="-100,0,0,100,0,0" Color="Black" Thickness="2">
    <tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D.Transform>
        <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0" OffsetY="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" OffsetZ="0" />
    </tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D.Transform>
</tool3d:ScreenSpaceLines3D>
```

Repeat for the other axis.

Comment: How could I get the position of the line after moving in C# code using your method?

Comment: The proper way to do it is to use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview). Instead of binding the transform directly to the slider you would would instead bind both the transform and the slider to a property in the page's [view model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern).